# How to compare specific rows in the same column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to compare rows 1st and 3rd across all columns in `df` below.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c( 5.2, -0.4, 3.0, 0.4), B = c( -3.5, 2.8, -0.4, 0.2), C = c( 4.4, 3.2, 4.0, -1.0), D = c(2.2, -1.4, 2.0, 0.7))


> df
     A    B    C    D
1  5.2 -3.5  4.4  2.2
2 -0.4  2.8  3.2 -1.4
3  3.0 -0.4  4.0  2.0
4  0.4  0.2 -1.0  0.7
```

I want to check if a value in the first row of column A is higher than a value in the third row of column A. If a value in the first row of column A is not higher than a value in the third row of column A, then the whole column should be removed. Then it is the same process for the other columns.

The expected outcome would be

```
 > df
         A    C    D
    1  5.2   4.4  2.2
    2 -0.4   3.2 -1.4
    3  3.0   4.0  2.0
    4  0.4  -1.0  0.7
```

Comment: Try `df[,df[1,]-df[3,]>0]`.